# Select Count in JDBC with Multiple clauses

Tags: java, sql, select, jdbc, count

I am trying to create a query, which searches for a multiple combination of  specific injury and fitness.

Here is the working mysql query:

```
Select  count(*) from Details WHERE injury= 'Critical' and fitness = 'Decreasing ' or  injury= 'Critical' and fitness= 'Stable ' or injury= 'Critical' and fitness= 'Increasing ' or injury= 'Light' and fitness= 'Decreasing' or injury= 'Light' and fitness= 'Decreasing' ;
```

However I am getting syntax errors, when using the sql query in JDBC. Is there something different I should be doing?

this is the java code that calls the sql

```
public void SelectSpecial() {
    Connection connect = DButilities.connectionToDatabase("PlayerDB"); 
      String query = "Select COUNT (*) from playerDetails WHERE injury= 'Critical' and fitness= 'Decreasing ' ";
```

Error Message

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax
> for the right syntax to use near '*);

Comment: Please show the Java code that calls JDBC.

Comment: @Dokksen Why did you removed the error message? Seems very relevant to me.

Comment: @EtienneMiret Oh you are right, I did not recognize it while editing the question, sorry for that, I will edit it back. Thank you!

Comment: @forpas apologies, i was trying something different and forgot to replicate the original try, should be fixed now